# Enabling integrated mouse in Samsung Q1 Ultra Premium (SQ1UP)

Tags: 15.04, mouse, samsung, touchscreen

I have this nice little UMPC device and I want to make it work under 15.04:

[SQ1UP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EV0XI.gif)

For now I was able to set up everything but an integreted mouse. A jog dial you can see on the left is a trackpoint/joystick input device. It can be switched between these two modes, the swith is hardware operated so it works idependently from the OS.

The joystick mode works out of the box, it just sends the same keycodes as arrows on the keyboard.

The mouse mode does not work. It worked out of the box on Ubuntu < 10.10, but the touscreen didn't. Now it's the other way around. Both touscreen (eGalax) and mouse are connected as one USB device:

```
cat /proc/bus/input/devices
I: Bus=0003 Vendor=0eef Product=0001 Version=0112
N: Name="Touchkit Touch"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:1d.1-1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/0003:0EEF:0001.0003/input/input12
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event6 js
B: PROP=0
B: EV=1b
B: KEY=30000 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=3
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=0eef Product=0001 Version=0112
N: Name="Touchkit Touch"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:1d.1-1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/0003:0EEF:0001.0003/input/input13
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event7
B: PROP=0
B: EV=1
B: KEY=401 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=3
B: MSC=10
```

There are some manuals for setting it up Xorg.conf file, but they're no longer valid in Ubuntu since we have Xorg.conf.d and separate configuration files.

Any ideas on how a configuration file for this case should look like?

Thanks

darkdude